# XML file issue adding extra content after modify and saving <//>

Tags: php, html, xml

After modifying xml file and saving the file in .txt extra content adding

Please find the below extra content 
`<//>`

Please suggest on this.

Comment: where is the extra content ?

Comment: this is extra "< // >" content

Comment: Before modification 

</Yahoo/>"


</Gmail/>


</Twitter/>


</sms/>


</SAM/>













After modification 

</Yahoo/>


</Gmail/>


"<//>" extra content


</Twitter/>


</sms/>


</SAM/>

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take some time to read the help section of the site, including [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). It's very difficult for anyone to help you when you provide so little information.

Answer (score 0):

`<//>` is not allowed in an XML file.

Perhaps you meant one of the following, each of which would be allowed:

1. `</tag>` to close an open `<tag>`
2. `<tag/>` to represent `<tag></tag>`
3. `<![CDATA[<//>]]>`
4. `&lt;//>`

The first two are different, but syntactically similar, constructs; the second two are ways to represent `<//>` in an XML file.

Furthermore, per the data listed in [your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50924449/xml-file-issue-adding-extra-content-after-modify-and-saving#comment88848384_50924449), `</tag/>` is also not allowed in XML.  See #1 for the most likely correction here for each of the opening and closing tags.